# Compensate mean of a mean reverting process in logs

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following stochastic process

$$
d\ln Y_t = -k\ln Y_tdt+ \sigma dW_t
$$

which has as solution

$$
\ln Y_T = \ln Y_0e^{-kT} + \int^T_0 \sigma e^{-k(T-s)}dW_s
$$

When I look at the expectation of $Y_t$ I have

$$
E[Y_T] = e^{E[\ln Y_T] + \frac{1}{2}V[\ln Y_T]}
$$

I want the process to be compensated so that $\frac{1}{2}V[\ln Y_T]$ drops from $E[Y_T]$

I know that

$$
V[\ln Y_T] = \frac{\sigma^2}{2k}(1-e^{-2kT})
$$

Is there a way determine what factor needs to be subtracted from the drift of $d\ln Y_t$ such that $E[Y_T]=e^{E[\ln Y_T]}$?

Comment: Sorry @Thomas Kojar I realised that the question has a number of things that did not make sense. I've just edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that
$$\tag{1}
\ln Y_T=e^{-kT}\ln Y_0+\int_0^T\sigma e^{-k(T-s)}\,dW_s
$$
is the solution to
$$\tag{2}
d(\ln Y_t)=-k\ln Y_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t\,.
$$
Let's write $X_t=\ln Y_t$ so that
$$\tag{3}
dX_t=-kX_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t\,.
$$
Applying Ito to $Y_t=e^{X_t}$ gives
$$\tag{4}
dY_t=-k\,Y_t\,X_t\,dt+\sigma\,Y_t\,dW_t+\frac12\sigma^2Y_t\,dt\,.
$$
This is often written as
$$\tag{5}
\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}=-k\,\ln Y_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t+\frac12\sigma^2\,dt\,
$$
and is a special case of the Black-Karaskinski interest rate model in mathematical finance. Comparing (2) and (5) shows that $d\ln Y_t$ is *not* $dY_t/Y_t$ as in ordinary calculus.

To get $\mathbb E[Y_t]$ we use the following facts:

- From (1) we see that $X_T$ is normally distributed with expectation
  $$\tag{6}
  e^{-kT}\ln Y_0=\ln\big((Y_0)^{e^{-kT}}\big)
  $$
  and that $Y_T=e^{X_T}$ is of the form
  $$\tag{7}
  Y_T=(Y_0)^{e^{-kT}}\,e^Z
  $$
  where $Z$ is the mean zero normal random variable given by the
  $dW$-term in (1).
- The variance of this $Z$-term is
  $$\tag{8}
  V=\int_0^T\sigma^2 e^{-2k(T-s)}\,ds=\sigma^2e^{-2kT}\frac{e^{2kT}-1}{2k}=\sigma^2\frac{1-e^{-2kT}}{2k}\,.
  $$
- The expectation of $e^{Z}$ for any $Z\sim N(0,V)$ is
  $$\tag{9}
  \mathbb E[e^Z]=e^{V/2}\,
  $$
  (the proof of this is elementary).

Altogether we have
$$\tag{10}
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}\mathbb E[Y_T]=(Y_0)^{e^{-kT}}e^{V/2}\quad}
$$
with the variance $V$ from (8).

To address the question made in the comments how to modify (2) so that
$$\tag{11}
\mathbb E[Y_T]=(Y_0)^{e^{-kT}}
$$
holds. This should be easy.
Obviously,
with
$$\tag{12}
U_t:=Y_t\,e^{-V_t/2}\,,\quad\text{ with } \quad V_t=\sigma^2\frac{1-e^{-2kt}}{2k}
$$
has the desired expectation. The SDE that is solved by $U_t$ is found from
Ito's integration by parts formula:
$$\tag{13}
dU_t=e^{-V_t/2}\,dY_t-\tfrac12Y_t\,e^{-V_t/2}\,dV_t=U_t\,\frac{dY_t}{Y_t}-\tfrac12 U_t\,dV_t\,.
$$
Using (5) this becomes
\begin{align}\tag{14}
dU_t=U_t\Big(-k\,\ln Y_t\,dt+\sigma\,dW_t+\tfrac12\sigma^2\,dt-\tfrac12\,dV_t\Big)\,.
\end{align}
Replacing $\ln Y_t$ by $\ln U_t+\tfrac{V_t}{2}$ we see that this becomes an SDE for $U_t\,.$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kurt. However, I am not sure this answers the question. I know the expectation of $E[Y_T] = (Y_0)^{e^{-kT}}e^{\frac{1}{2}V}$, my question is how can I modify equation (2) such that  $E[Y_T] = (Y_0)^{e^{-kT}}$. I.e. the variance term vanishes. From knowing how to get to (1) from (2) I think that adding a term $ \frac{\sigma^2}{2} e^{-k(T-t)}dt $ to (2) will make the variance vanish. However, I believe I've obtained the number a bit heuristically and I was wondering if there is a more rigorous method

Comment: Thanks @Kurt. Just a quick question, is there a typo in $V_t$ in (12)? should $V_t$ be the same as in equation (8) and the denominator should be $2k$ instead of $2t$?

Comment: @konnoc84 I agree with the denominator (just fixed it). I think however we want the $T$ in (8) to become a $t$. Otherwise it will be difficult to derive the SDE for $U_t\,.$ But this is not a problem because $U_T$ carries the $V$ from (8) you wanted.

Comment: one last question (which I admit I am a bit ashamed of asking because I think I should know the answer) $dV_t = \frac{dV}{dt}dt$ which is $\frac{\partial V_t}{\partial t}dt$ because $V_t$ only depends on t for this purpose?

Comment: Yes. $dV_t=\sigma^2\,e^{-2kt}\,dt\,.$